# timespan mm/:ss formatting correct working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, timespan

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:mm\:ss}")]
[Column("delay", TypeName = "interval")]
        public TimeSpan Delay{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Delay, @"{0:mm\:ss}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In textbox,everything fine with display format, but when i try to save it, system convert minutes to hours and seconds to minutes. And i don't understand why. Any solutions?

Comment: TimeSpan expects data in the format `HH:mm:ss`. If your expecting `10:00` to represent `00:10:00` (and not the default `10:00:00`) then you will need to create a custom ModelBinder to set the value.